# Warning: Implicit declaration of function 'min' is invalid in C99

Tags: ios, objective-c, error-handling

so i bought this app, and the developer is in no way to get in contact with about the problem, so i'm hoping i can get some help here.

When i build the app in Xcode, i get an error saying:

```
GGDraggableView.m: Implicit declaration of function 'min' is invalid in C99
```

I'm not that good at Obj-c or Swift yet, so im still learning.
I've tried to look the error up on google and in here, but can't really get any of the answers to work.

Whats wrong?
Here's the whole class and a picture of the error:
[image]

```
#import "GGDraggableView.h"
#import "GGOverlayView.h"

@interface GGDraggableView ()
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGestureRecognizer;
@property(nonatomic) CGPoint originalPoint;
@property(nonatomic, strong) GGOverlayView *overlayView;
@end

@implementation GGDraggableView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (!self) return nil;

    
    self.overlayView = [[GGOverlayView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    self.overlayView.alpha = 0;
    [self addSubview:self.overlayView];

    return self;
}

-(void)awakeFromNib
{

    self.panGestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dragged:)];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:self.panGestureRecognizer];
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

}

- (void)loadImageAndStyle
{
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bar"]];
    [self addSubview:imageView];
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(7, 7);
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
}

- (void)dragged:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    CGFloat xDistance = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:self].x;
    CGFloat yDistance = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:self].y;

    switch (gestureRecognizer.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:{
            self.originalPoint = self.center;
            break;
        };
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:{
            CGFloat rotationStrength = MIN(xDistance / 320, 1);
            CGFloat rotationAngel = (CGFloat) (2*M_PI/16 * rotationStrength);
            CGFloat scaleStrength = 1 - fabs(rotationStrength) / 4;
            CGFloat scale = MAX(scaleStrength, 0.93);
            CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotationAngel);
            CGAffineTransform scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, scale, scale);
            self.transform = scaleTransform;
            self.center = CGPointMake(self.originalPoint.x + xDistance, self.originalPoint.y + yDistance);

            [self updateOverlay:xDistance];

            break;
        };
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded: {
            [self resetViewPositionAndTransformations];
            break;
        };
        case UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible:break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled:break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed:break;
    }
}

- (void)updateOverlay:(CGFloat)distance
{
    if (distance > 0) {
        self.overlayView.mode = GGOverlayViewModeRight;
    } else if (distance <= 0) {
        self.overlayView.mode = GGOverlayViewModeLeft;
    }
    CGFloat overlayStrength = min(fabdistance) / 100; 0.4;
    self.overlayView.alpha = overlayStrength;
}

- (void)resetViewPositionAndTransformations
{
    if (self.center.x < 50)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                         animations:^{
                             self.center = CGPointMake(-self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2);
                             self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
                             self.overlayView.alpha = 0;
                         } completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         
                             if (finished)
                                 self.center = self.originalPoint;
                                 }];
            }
    else if (self.center.x > 270)
    {
       [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                             animations:^{
                                 self.center = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width *2, self.frame.size.height/2);
                                 self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
                                 self.overlayView.alpha = 0;
                             } completion:^(BOOL finished){
                                 
                                 if (finished)
                                    self.center = self.originalPoint;
                             }];

        
    }
    else
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                         animations:^{
                             self.center = self.originalPoint;
                             self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
                             self.overlayView.alpha = 0;
                         }];
    
    }
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [self removeGestureRecognizer:self.panGestureRecognizer];
}

@end
```

I hope you guys, can help me on the right path here, or magically come with a fix.

Thanks in advance

Comment: u have a wrong semicolon in that line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that the `min(a)` function has not been defined. As the previous developer was using elsewhere in the code, the macro you're looking for is fully uppercase `MIN(a, b)` and takes two parameters, returning the smallest.

Your call should be:

```
CGFloat overlayStrength = MIN(fabdistance / 100, 0.4);
```

Comment: Thanks for the description, makes more sense. And it worked perfectly. Thank you so much, for the fast respond!